# TypeError:LoadLibrary() argument 1 must be str, not None

Tags: python, python-3.x, ctypes, anaconda3

I have been trying to learn SpeechRecognition in python, so I decided working with code provided by Picovoice Github, When I tried running the script in Colab it works fine. But it fails to do so when I run in my desktop.

```
C:\Users\ELCOT\Downloads\cheetah-master\cheetah-master>python demo/python/cheetah_demo.py --audio_paths resources/audio_samples/test.wav --license_path license_cta_v1.2.0_linux_expires_2020-08-27.lic
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "demo/python/cheetah_demo.py", line 61, in <module>
    license_path=args.license_path)
  File "demo/python\../../binding/python\cheetah.py", line 63, in __init__
    self._libc = CDLL(find_library('c'))
  File "C:\Python 36\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 348, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
TypeError: LoadLibrary() argument 1 must be str, not None
```

I tried with Anaconda too, it shows me the same error. I am stuck in this for couple of week, please help. (I am using python 3.6.8 X64 in win 10)
Will completely reinstalling anaconda do the work?

Comment: Please don't spam tags. Has nothing to do with C or C++.

Comment: `LoadLibrary` is a Windows API function that loads a DLL. Its forst argument must be the name of the DLL to load. It seems that `cheetah.py` looks for a library called `'c'` and maybe can't find it. Apparently this is not checked. It continues and calls `dlopen` which then calls `LoadLibrary`, but the `self` seems uninitialized

Comment: On https://docs.python.org/2.5/lib/ctypes-finding-shared-libraries.html: "_find_library(name): Try to find a library and return a pathname_" And: "_On Windows, find_library searches along the system search path, and returns the full pathname, but since there is no predefined naming scheme a call like find_library("c") will fail and return None._"

Answer (score 1):

The error you experience comes from poor code you got from GitHub that does no error checking.

The relevant trace is:

```
self._libc = CDLL(find_library('c'))
self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
LoadLibrary()
```

It appears the `find_library` call could not locate the C library and so returned the value `None`.

That value is then used in the `dlopen` call which underneath uses the `LoadLibrary` function of the Windows API. However, this now uses an unknown name or empty parameter `None` and consequently fails.

On https://docs.python.org/2.5/lib/ctypes-finding-shared-libraries.html:

> `find_library(name)`: Try to find a library and return a pathname.
>
> On Windows, find_library searches along the system search path, and returns the full pathname, but since there is no predefined naming scheme a call like find_library("c") will fail and return None.

So a solution could be to add the location of the library (probably `libc.lib`) to the `PATH` environment variable.

Comment: But, I could not find libc.lib in my computer, how could I get it and its path to environment

Comment: I am sorry that I can't help you here. I added the `ctypes` tag and hope that maybe a Python expert can help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can't run the free version of Cheetah on Windows, it simply isn't supported.  The code in the GitHub repository only supports Linux.

The fourth bullet point in the [README](https://github.com/Picovoice/cheetah) is as follows (emphasis mine):

> - cross-platform. Linux (x86_64), Mac (x86_64), Windows (x86_64), web browsers, Android, iOS, Raspberry Pi, and BeagleBone are supported. **Linux (x86_64) is available for personal and non-commercial use free of charge. Other platforms are only available under the commercial license.**